# Mixed hadoop cluster

Tags: linux, windows, hadoop, cluster-computing

Is it possible to have windows and linux(centos,rhel) datanodes in a hadoop cluster . What are the configuration settings required for mixed cluster ?

Regards,
hadoop user

Answer (score 0):

pss
Make sure that Proper DNS resolution between your cluster(windows and linux). thats enough to form a cluster.

Comment: any reference to see the configuration settings in xml & environment files for such mixed cluster ?

Comment: simple multinode cluster -http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html
For HA cluster - you can configure the basic setting and add this conf http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html

Are you looking for exact conf files ??